# VBS to save binary64 picture data as .jpeg file

Tags: vbscript, jpeg, binary-data

I need to extract user pictures out of Active Directory (LDS) and save them as a .jpeg file. I am able to extract the binary 64 data for the photo attribute in AD but I don't know how to write it to a usable .jpeg file in my .vbs script. Please post sample code!

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: AD.get(..) -> bytes() -> ADODB.Stream -> Disk :: http://www.normanbauer.com/2011/08/12/how-to-display-active-directory-stored-user-account-pictures-in-windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the extracted binary data.. here's a sub to take that data and create a .jpg file.  Just pass the binary data and a path to save (ie. c:\temp\pic.jpg).

```
Sub writeImage(binaryData, strFullPath)

  Set objADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADO.Open
  objADO.Type = 1
  objADO.Position = 0

  objADO.Write binaryData
  objADO.SaveToFile strFullPath

  Set objADO = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you didn't have the data, you could use this to pull it from a URL.

```
Function binaryURL(strURL)
  Set objHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

  objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
  objHTTP.Send

  binaryURL = objHTTP.ResponseBody
End Function
```

And then just do a..

```
Call writeImage(binaryURL("http://i.imgur.com/fr16Y6W.jpg"), "C:\temp\pic.jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't use VBS often enough. I was struggling to get the binary data written to an image file that would be readable. I tried various methods that I found on Google unsuccessfully but this one worked!